# Brute force bash script with another bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

so i currently have a bash script that takes a hash value and then asks the user to input a password, converts their input to hash and then compares.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    crypt="8277e0910d750195b448797616e091ad"
    echo "please enter a password!"
    read inc
    hash="$((echo -n $inc|md5sum) | awk '{print $1}')"
    if [[ "$hash" == "$crypt" ]];
    then
        echo "logged in"
    else
        echo "incorrect pass"
    fi
```

I now want to create another program that brute forces this password by adding values(from a-z) into the password input but im running into trouble as i feel my knowledge on bash file manipulation is limited as ive never ran a script against another script before.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    for i in {a..z}; do
         (echo -n "$i: " && ./hashscript $i) | grep logged in
    done
```

Comment: `echo -n` is best avoided. `printf '%s' "$inc" | md5sum` is going to behave more consistently; see the APPLICATION USAGE notes in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html. That said, bash is the wrong tool for this job in general -- every time you run `md5sum` that's a `fork()` and an `execve()`. Every command substitution, every pipeline setup, &c. is expensive -- it's not so bad if you set up a pipeline and run a lot of inputs through it, but if you run one pipeline per piece of data you want to process, that's crazy slow.

Comment: What is the problem and what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Since the 1st script is reading the data from stdin (with `read`), the 2nd script will need to pass the data in that way:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {a..z}; do
     (echo -n "$i: " && echo $i | ./hashscript) | grep logged in
done
```